# mongo model fields not available in query string and GraphiQL query

Tags: python, mongodb, graphql, graphene-python, flask-graphql

I am creating a project to query a mongo schema in GraphQL.
I have a model which act as a mongo collection and schema file for mapping the model with graphql Query.
When i try to query the fields in mongo models only id is getting populated and not able to retrieve other fields.

Code snippet below:

```py
models.py
class A(EmbeddedDocument):
    content_length = StringField(name="content-length", required=True)
    expires = StringField()
    destination = StringField()
    subscription = StringField()
    priority = StringField()


class B(DynamicEmbeddedDocument):
    pass

class Store(Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'event_store'}
    one = EmbeddedDocumentField(A, required=True)
    two = EmbeddedDocumentField(B, required=True)

schema.py

class StoreType(MongoengineObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        interfaces = (Node,)

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    node = Node.Field()
    all_stores = MongoengineConnectionField(StoreType)
    store = graphene.Field(StoreType)

    def resolve_all_stores(parent, info, **kwargs):
        return list(EventStoreModel.objects.all())

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, types=[StoreType,])
```

Query in GraphIQL:
Current result:

```
query{
  allEvents{
    edges{
      node{
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
result
{
  "data": {
    "allEvents": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "RXZlbnQ6NWQwNjFiZTBiMjNjYTAwYTdmMDk5YTgy"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Expected result:

```
query{
  allEvents{
    edges{
      node{
        id,
        one,
        two
      }
    }
  }
}
{
  "data": {
    "allEvents": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "RXZlbnQ6NWQwNjFiZTBiMjNjYTAwYTdmMDk5YTgy",
            "one":[data],
            "two":[data]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

While querying i need fields from Store model(one, two).
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
class AField(MongoengineObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = B
        interfaces = (Node,)


class BField(MongoengineObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        interfaces = (Node,)
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps?